# CrafterCMS Create Site window blueprint dropdown is blank

Tags: content-management-system, crafter-cms

I have downloaded [craftercms](http://craftercms.org/downloads) and now following **Getting Started** [guide](http://docs.craftercms.org/en/stable/getting-started/your-first-website.html). But I don't see any blueprints in the blueprints dropdown. How can I get and install blueprints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the blueprints from here https://github.com/craftercms/studio/archive/v2.5.3.zip. Blueprints are located here: *src/main/webapp/repo-bootstrap/cstudio/blueprints/* within the file.

Now you can move the wanted Blueprint in the */cstudio/blueprints/* folder within your local repository

Comment: Blueprints could be downloaded as individual folders from https://github.com/craftercms/studio/tree/v2.5.3/src/main/webapp/repo-bootstrap/cstudio/blueprints (adjust URLs as per your Studio Version in future)